# Set value doesn't count the last row and overwrites in the first row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This script runs on timely basis and copies the data from one sheet to another depending on the conditions(Time and keyword)

For example:
Setvalue writes "Date" "Main Page" "Copied" in row 2
then
Setvalue writes "Date" "Andhra Pradesh" Copied" again in row 2.

Rather it should write the value in the last column.

```
var entry =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Logger');
var entryrange = entry.getDataRange();
var startRow=entry.getLastRow()+1;
var dt=new Date();
var today=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();
var lastdate=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()-32).valueOf();
var sh =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('master');
var csh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('mainpage');
 
function run(){
  mainfilter();
  andhrafilter();
  assamfilter();
}

function mainfilter() {
var vA=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var found=false;
var output=[];
for (var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
var date=new Date(vA[i][0]);
var dv=new Date(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth(),date.getDate()).valueOf();
if (dv>=lastdate && dv<=today) {
output.push([vA[i][0],vA[i][1],vA[i][2],vA[i][3],vA[i][4],vA[i][6],vA[i][8]]);
found=true;
}
}
if(found) {
csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,output.length,output[0].length).setValues(output);
entry.getRange(startRow,1,1,1).setValue(dt);
entry.getRange(startRow,2,1,1).setValue("Main Page");
entry.getRange(startRow,3,1,1).setValue("Copied");
}else{
entry.getRange(startRow,1,1,1).setValue(dt);
entry.getRange(startRow,2,1,1).setValue("Main Page");
entry.getRange(startRow,3,1,1).setValue("No data");
}
}


function andhrafilter() {
var vA1=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var csh1=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('andhra');
var target1='Andhra Pradesh';
var found1=false;
var output1=[];
for (var i1=0;i1<vA1.length;i1++) {
var date1=new Date(vA1[i1][0]);
var dv1=new Date(date1.getFullYear(),date1.getMonth(),date1.getDate()).valueOf();
if (dv1>=lastdate && dv1<=today && vA1[i1][7]==target1) {
output1.push([vA1[i1][0],vA1[i1][1],vA1[i1][2],vA1[i1][3],vA1[i1][4],vA1[i1][6],vA1[i1][8]]);
found1=true;
}
}
if(found1) {
csh1.getRange(csh1.getLastRow()+1,1,output1.length,output1[0].length).setValues(output1);
entry.getRange(startRow,1,1,1).setValue(dt);
entry.getRange(startRow,2,1,1).setValue("Andhra Pradesh");
entry.getRange(startRow,3,1,1).setValue("Copied");
}
else{
entry.getRange(startRow,1,1,1).setValue(dt);
entry.getRange(startRow,2,1,1).setValue("Andhra Pradesh");
entry.getRange(startRow,3,1,1).setValue("No data");
}
}

function assamfilter() {
var vA4=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var csh4=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('assam');
var target4='Assam';
var found4=false;
var output4=[];
for (var i4=0;i4<vA4.length;i4++) {
var date4=new Date(vA4[i4][0]);
var dv4=new Date(date4.getFullYear(),date4.getMonth(),date4.getDate()).valueOf();
if (dv4>=lastdate && dv4<=today && vA4[i4][7]==target4) {
output4.push([vA4[i4][0],vA4[i4][1],vA4[i4][2],vA4[i4][3],vA4[i4][4],vA4[i4][6],vA4[i4][8]]);
found4=true;
}
}
if(found4) {
csh4.getRange(csh4.getLastRow()+1,1,output4.length,output4[0].length).setValues(output4);
entry.getRange(startRow,1,1,1).setValue(dt);
entry.getRange(startRow,2,1,1).setValue("Assam");
entry.getRange(startRow,3,1,1).setValue("Copied");
}
else{
entry.getRange(startRow,1,1,1).setValue(dt);
entry.getRange(startRow,2,1,1).setValue("Assam");
entry.getRange(startRow,3,1,1).setValue("No data");
}
}
```

[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kypsGYJkPl1r5S8z3cz65wuc8jOH4zrB__AyQKOl3_E/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Only solution that I have: declare unique variables in every function which will count the rows and then set the value. So that a value is already placed before next function runs. 
The only thing is I have 36 function with the exact same work. Only thing is they copy to different sheets.

Comment: I would need to see an image of your data but I suspect you are not accounting for the header row.

Comment: Please share a copy / sample of your sheet

Comment: I will be sharing the sample sheet soon. 
@Cooper No the header row remains untouched. Row 2 fills by the setvalue in mainfilter() and then Row 2 is again overwritten by andhrafilter(). 

The things is when andhrafilter() runs setvalue then it should write in Row 3 (the last row)

Comment: Shared with the link. Please help

Comment: I found and changed one thing 
var startRow=entry.getLastRow()+1; 
Added this in every function and it works fine. Every time a function runs then the last row is read successfully. Any other input from your side will be appreciated.

Comment: @DilshadAkhtar so what I understand is that you expect `"Date, Main Page, Copied"`, `"Date, Andhra Pradesh, Copied"` and `"Date, Assam, Copied"` in different rows in the "Logger" tab?